# Don't understand cause of TypeError when checking words

Tags: python, spacy

I need to check if a word from a list exists in a pdf file, but I have some problems with the error `TypeError: argument of type 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' is not iterable`, and I don't understand how can I fix it.

```
word_list = ['Education', 'Skills']    
for word in word_list:
        lst = []
        for sentence in words:
            if word in sentence: 
               lst.append(word)
        print('{0} key word(s) in sentence: {1}'.format(len(lst), ', '.join(lst)))
        print(sentence + "\n")
```

Comment: We need to see the entire traceback to have a chance of helping you. Pleasae [edit] your question and add it.

Comment: in this line:
`for sentence in words:`
you have words that is not define
do you mean in 'word'?

Comment: This code does not use the spacy library at all, but your error indicates the use of a spacy `Token` type. Whatever caused the error is not present in the question.

Comment: The trace error and snippet of code seem unrelated. Where is ‘words’ defined?

Comment: Words is tokenization of text in my document

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant to do is this:

```
word_list = ['Education', 'Skills']    
lst = []
for word in word_list:
    if word in sentence: 
        lst.append(word)

if len(last) > 0:
    print('{0} key word(s) in sentence: {1}'.format(len(lst), ', '.join(lst)))
    print(sentence + "\n")
```

where `sentence` is a string. I think you probably made a typo with `words`, and it's been defined earlier as a spacy token, leading to this confusing error message.